# Firebase Cloud Messaging APIs and SDKs is related to GA4

Tags: firebase, sdk, google-cloud-messaging, google-analytics-4

I am not a developer, but I work with Firebase/Ga4 to get event tracking from an app. I was wondering, as I am not a developer, if the Firebase Cloud Messaging API and SDK are anyway related to GA4? As far as I look for it, I think it is not. The SDK for GA4 is Firebase SDK/Google Analytics for Firebase, but just in case...

I search for the name of the GA4 SDK in Firebase and I get always the name Firebase SDK/Google Analytics SDK. I expect confirmation that the need to update this SDKs as nothing to do with GA4 and the tracking of events in the app remains the same.

Legacy HTTP Protocol
XMPP Protocol
Batch send API
GCM register API
Legacy Web register API
Instance ID Server API for Web
Server keys
iOS Direct Channel

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Cloud Messaging and Google Analytics 4 can be used in isolation. Neither of them requires the other.